# std::cout don't work with overloaded '<<' operator for struct

Tags: c++, struct, operator-overloading, std

I've implemented operator '<<' overloading for struct LevelStats , which seems to work well with files , but encounter problem when used with std::cout

header file:

```
struct LevelStats
{
    DIFFICULTY level;
    std::chrono::duration<double> best_time;
    unsigned int games_played;
    unsigned int games_won;

};

std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream &os, const LevelStats &stats);
```

cpp file:

```
std::ofstream &operator<<(std::ofstream &os, const LevelStats &stats) {
    os << static_cast<unsigned int>(stats.level) << " " << "Best_Time= " << stats.best_time.count()<<std::endl;
    os << static_cast<unsigned int>(stats.level) << " " << "Games_Played= " << stats.games_played<<std::endl;
    os << static_cast<unsigned int>(stats.level) << " " << "Games_Won= " << stats.games_won<<std::endl;

    return os;
}
```

That works well with for operations like

> file << LevelStats object

, but when used as

> std::cout << LevelStats object

results with :

> error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}'
>   lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream&&'

Edit: Replaced with std::ostream& meets the same error
Another Edit : Dumb mistake in arguments - it works

Comment: Change all occurrences of `ofstream` to `ostream`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `operator<<` is declared as

```cpp
std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream &os, const LevelStats &stats);
```

Notice that you're passing and returning a reference to `std::ofstream`.
Writing to file will work because you will pass a `std::ofstream&`, but `std::cout` is not a `std::ofstream&` and can not bind to `std::ofstream&`.

If you want to be able to output your `struct` using `std::cout` while still beeing able to use `std::ofstream`, change your `operator<<` to

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const LevelStats &stats);
```

Both `std::ofstream` and `std::ostream` can bind to `std::ostream &os`, allowing you to write your `struct` to both files and `std::cout`.